# How to get Telephone Number In Android

Tags: android

I want to get the telephone Number.
I used this sample code..

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String strphonenumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

And I used the permission- READ_PHONE_STATE.

But its returning null.

Comment: What type of device are you running this on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only be able to get the Number from a CDMA device.

```
public String returnNumber() {
     String number = null;
     String service = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
     TelephonyManager tel_manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(service);
     int device_type = tel_manager.getPhoneType();

     switch (device_type) {
           case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
              number = tel_manager.getLine1Number();
           break;
           default:
             //return something else
             number = "no number";
            break;
     }
     return number;
}
```

Comment: If it is something unique you need why not try use getDeviceId() which will return IMEA for GSM. If you have to have the number then on GSM it's very sketchy and unreliable...

Comment: Yeah..But I seeing the way to get telephone number.